# SQL Simple Join and I'm stumped

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with columns:

```
JOB_NUM, HM_PH, BUS_PH, CALL1ST
```

Where the `job_num` is a unique number

And the `HM_PH`, `BUS_PH`, and `CALL1ST` columns are 10 digit phone numbers

So using the order of columns above, sample data would look like:

```
JOB_NUM, HM_PH,      BUS_PH,     CALL1ST
------------------------------------
12345,   4025557848, 9165897588, 7518884455  
10101,   8887776655, 8667416895, 5558884446
```

What I want to produce is 2 columns.

```
JOB_NUM, PHONE
```

Where the job_num is listed next to every phone number such as:

```
JOB_NUM PHONE
---------------------
12345   4025557848  
12345   9165897588  
12345   7518884455  
10101   8887776655  
10101   8667416895  
10101   5558884446
```

Where do I start?

Comment: @OMG I am glad that I double checked before dropping my revisions right over the top of yours. ;)

Comment: @ahsteele: anyway there are revisions, you always can rollback ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a UNION (if you want to remove duplicate rows) or UNION ALL (if you want to keep duplicate rows):

```
SELECT JOB_NUM, HM_PH AS PHONE FROM yourtable
UNION
SELECT JOB_NUM, BUS_PH FROM yourtable
UNION
SELECT JOB_NUM, CALL1ST FROM yourtable
ORDER BY JOB_NUM
```

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome: Mind that `UNION` will remove duplicates; `UNION ALL` will not, and be faster for it.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: +1 Good point. Added. @JNK: Fixed that too, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make a UNION ALL for all numbers you need (with duplicates) or UNION when you need unique rows:

```
select JOB_NUM,HM_PH AS PHONE
from YourTableName
union all
select JOB_NUM,BUS_PH AS PHONE
from YourTableName
union all
select JOB_NUM,CALL1ST_PH AS PHONE
from YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table yourtable
(
    id int,
    HM_PH nvarchar(10),
    BUS_PH nvarchar(10),
    CALL1ST nvarchar(10)
)


insert into yourtable
select 12345,   4025557848, 9165897588, 7518884455  
union
select 10101,   8887776655, 8667416895, 5558884446



select * from yourtable

select ID,p.Phone
from temptemp
unpivot( Phone for phoneCol in (HM_PH,BUS_PH,CALL1ST)) p
order by id 

 drop table yourtable
```